Google Cloud storing Entity to Memcache
After two weeks of trying to find a solution, I am quite desperate to find (and I have read everything related to the topic) any way to resolve the issue.
I am reworking server because Java 8 has reached end of support on Google Cloud. I am migrating to Java 11. I have been able to set Jetty server and store/get Entities from Google Cloud Datastore. However, I can't find any way to store Entities in Memcache. Before (Java 8), it was very easy and straightforward but this code doesn't work anymore and I am stuck to replace this code on Java 11.
Old code:
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheService;
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceFactory;

MemcacheService syncCache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
Entity entity;
Key key;

public void load(){
    entity = (Entity)syncCache.get(key);
}
public void save(){
    syncCache.put(key,entity);
}
...
...
...

Is there any similiar solution to access Google Cloud Memcache in Java 11? Thank you a lot for any help.
